# Servo Tester Only Works When Power and PWM are On Same Battery, Why?

Tags: servo

[image]

I am having a problem when switching my servo power supply from the microcontroller to a separate battery pack. Fortunately, I was able to replicate the problem with two different cheapo servo testers, as shown below.

In my understanding:

1. The white (control PWM) cable works as a glorified relay - it tells the servo to give or cut power.
2. There is NO feedback to the servo tester from the servo potentiometer - that's an internal Servo thing to align angle based on PWM.

With those givens, where is my gap in understanding, why does the second diagram not work, and how do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PWM signal has an undefined reference voltage level, because there is no common ground.

Short the negative poles of both battery packs.

Comment: Hi Cristoph, thank you, I don't quite understand the theory, could you elaborate please? Where in the chain is this being measured / causing failure? I will try now btw, thank you again - I tried sharing a ground directly and that didn't work, but I will short them.

Furthermore, this seems iffy on a microcontroller (connecting microcontroller and battery pack ground) or am I overthinking?

Comment: This works btw, danke, just tested in my diagram there (with the actual gear). Going to make it work with the microcontroller now. Still a bit lost, because then the ground is going to be common for all servos, but I guess that doesn't matter?

Comment: The servo "compares" the PWM input to its ground, coming from the upper battery pack. Your servo tester has a different ground (the lower battery pack), which means that the voltage levels of the PWM signal w.r.t. the servo-ground are not defined.

Comment: If you are afraid of connecting the servo-grounds, you need servos with isolated PWM inputs.

Comment: Looks like I need to learn more fundamentals. This unblocks me though. Thanks again!